# Set Thresholds on a Decision Tree?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, decision-tree

Can someone explain to me what is the purpose of the `setThresholds()` function on Gradient Boosted Trees and Random Forest in Apache Spark? There is no documentation or example in the official Apache Spark website where that function is used and I am curious to see if I can use it for my particular purpose. Does this function sets thresholds on the internal decisions the tree makes? For example, for a numeric column, using `setThresholds(5.0)` is equivalent to `if(column < 5.0)`? or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't seem to have check the right parts of the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassifier@thresholds:org.apache.spark.ml.param.DoubleArrayParam).

The `thresholds` value is defined as following :

> Param for Thresholds in multi-class classification to adjust the probability of predicting each class. Array must have length equal to the number of classes, with values >= 0. The class with largest value p/t is predicted, where p is the original probability of that class and t is the class' threshold.

And you have noticed that's in fact *thresholds* in plural and not just one threshold.

You can set thresholds using `setThresholds(foo)` where `foo` are the values of the thresholds.

Comment: It doesn't show up here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/GBTClassifier.html#getThresholds--

Comment: It seems as if all the support is given only to Scala or Python and not Java. Most methods are not explained at all in the Java API Documentation

Comment: Indeed. I haven't noticed that before. I merely never use the Java API tbh